# Generate Automatic increment for "alt" html field on images

Tags: php, auto-increment

I'm using a php gallery script and I need to add numbers (auto increment) in the "alt" field (images).
I already tried several options from stackoverflow and unfortunately I didn't succeed.

For example:
For each image added, alt field should be like this:

```
alt="adidas 1">
alt="adidas 2">
alt="adidas 3">
alt="adidas and more">
```

My HTML output should be like:

```
<div class="gallery">
<img src="./products/adidas-cushon.webp"/ alt="adidas 1">
<img src="./products/adidas-majestic.webp"/ alt="adidas 2">
<img src="./products/adidas-wear.webp"/ alt="adidas 3">
</div>
```

My script

```
<!-- (A) CSS & JS -->
<link href="gallery/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="gallery/gallery.js"></script>
 
<div class="gallery"><?php
// (B) GET LIST OF IMAGE FILES FROM GALLERY FOLDER
$dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "./products/adidas/" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$images = glob("$dir*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,webp}", GLOB_BRACE);
//rsort($images); // high to low
//sort($images); // low to high
natsort ($images); // 

// (C) OUTPUT IMAGES 
foreach ($images as $i) {
  printf('<img src="./products/adidas/%s" alt="adidas">', basename($i));
}
?></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just increment a variable? Initialize it with 0 before the loop and you're done.

Comment: Just change to this: `$i = 0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    printf('<img src="./products/adidas/%s" alt="adidas %d">', basename($image), ++$i);
}`. If you need to count on same names, just create an array for that.

Comment: I tried this: 
```$i = 0;
// (C) OUTPUT IMAGES 
foreach ($images as $i) {
  printf('<img src="./products/adidas/%s" alt="adidas %d">', basename($i), ++$i);
}
?></div>```

The outpot is:  
```<img src="./products/adidas-cushon.webp"/ alt="adidas 0">
<img src="./products/adidas-majestic.webp"/ alt="adidas 0">
<img src="./products/adidas-wear.webp"/ alt="adidas 0">```

Comment: Don't use `$i` for both the image and the counter.

Comment: I tried this code and i think is working perfect! Should i modify something on him?
Thank you!

```$x = 0;
// (C) OUTPUT IMAGES 
foreach ($images as $i) {
  printf('<img src="./products/adidas/%s" alt="adidas %d">', basename($i), ++$x);
}
?></div>```

Answer (score 1):

Use the array index key in your foreach and add 1.

```php
foreach ($images as $i => $path) {
  printf('<img src="./products/adidas/%s" alt="adidas %s">', basename($path),$i+1);
}
```